# Read in JPEG, resize it and save it to disk

Tags: c++, windows, jpeg, libjpeg

## What I want:

Resize an existing jpeg into a new, smaller one.

Example: before_3000x2000.jpeg →→→ after_1024x768.jpeg

I think I'll need pseudo-functions like these:

> foo( before_file_path, after_file_path, new_width, new_height )

which makes use of

> decompress_jpeg( before_file_path )
>
> resize( decompressed_data, new_width, new_height )
>
> compress_jpeg( resized_data )
>
> save_jpeg( compressed_data, after_file_path )

Please correct my approach if I misunderstood something.

## What I assume:

- Since the resolutions will vary, first you have to decompress the existing jpeg so you can properly work with the pixel data.
- Second, you resize the pixeldata to a smaller buffer with some function foo().
- Third, you compress said buffer and save it to disk.

## What I tried (and failed):

For starters, I tried playing around with the

> write_JPEG_file (char * filename, int quality)

function provided in ***example.c*** of ***jpeglib-9b***. I just want to write out a test-picture in whatever resolution I specify with a single colour. But I run into a problem. I ***think*** I'm writing out random memory and I dont know why. (here is a picture: [img_100x100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O51wy.jpg)) Notice how at the top there is white colour up to a certain point. This part changes accordingly to what I assign in the first loop. But after a certain amount it changes to random noise. ***Why?***

## What I changed:

I defined `image_width, image_height, image_buffer`
I replaced all `fopen(...)` with `fopen_s(...)`.
I hardcoded the quality to 100 in `jpeg_set_quality(...)`

## Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jpeg-9b\jpeglib.h"
#include "jpeg-9b\jerror.h"

int TEST_WRITE_JPEG(char* file_name)
{
    // DEFINE A PIC HERE
    const int image_width = 100;        /* Number of columns in image */
    const int image_height = 100;   /* Number of rows in image */
    JSAMPLE* image_buffer = new JSAMPLE[image_width * image_height]();  /* Points to large array of R,G,B-order data */
    for (int i = 0; i < image_width*image_height; i++)
    {
        image_buffer[i] = 255;
    }

    /* Step 1: allocate and initialize JPEG compression object */
    struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
    FILE * outfile;
    JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];
    int row_stride;

    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
    jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);

    /* Step 2: specify data destination (eg, a file) */
    if (fopen_s(&outfile, file_name, "wb") != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", file_name);
        exit(1);
    }
    jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, outfile);

    /* Step 3: set parameters for compression */
    cinfo.image_width = image_width;    /* image width and height, in pixels */
    cinfo.image_height = image_height;
    cinfo.input_components = 3;         /* # of color components per pixel */
    cinfo.in_color_space = JCS_RGB;     /* colorspace of input image */

    jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);
    jpeg_set_quality(&cinfo, 100, TRUE);

    /* Step 4: Start compressor */
    jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, TRUE);

    /* Step 5: while (scan lines remain to be written) */
    row_stride = image_width * 3;

    while (cinfo.next_scanline < cinfo.image_height)
    {
        row_pointer[0] = (JSAMPROW)&image_buffer[cinfo.next_scanline * row_stride];
        (void)jpeg_write_scanlines(&cinfo, row_pointer, 1);
    }

    /* Step 6: Finish compression */
    jpeg_finish_compress(&cinfo);
    /* After finish_compress, we can close the output file. */
    fclose(outfile);

    /* Step 7: release JPEG compression object */
    /* This is an important step since it will release a good deal of memory. */
    jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);

    return 0;
}
```

## Clear questions:

Why do I write out [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O51wy.jpg) picture and not a plain white one?
Why does the program crash if `image_buffer` contains more than 128x128 unsigned chars?

Comment: You don't want to do this. You want to save it with a lower Q. This approach will pixilate the data.

Comment: @EJP I dont want to do what specifically? I assume you're talking about the resizing part? Could you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 bytes are used for each pixels, so you have to allocate `3 * image_width * image_height` elements while you allocated only `image_width * image_height` elements. Allocate and initialize sufficient elements.

Comment: Yes, 3 seconds after I hit submit I immediately saw that. Wow this is embarrassing. Thank you very much! That fixed everything. No crash and works perfectly for larger sizes. Can't accept your answer yet, since it is so early.